# How to configure HTC Desire for 3g connectivity in Peru?

Tags: htc-desire, settings, 3g

How can I configure an unlocked HTC Desire for 3g connectivity in Peru?

I have managed to add an APN so that I have EDGE but I would like to use Claro's 3.5g.

I also have an iPhone with the same kind of dataplan that has 3g pre-configured so I am hoping that it is possible.

I realize that this is a very specific question but I can´t get any worse help than at the Claro office...

Comment: Were you able to connect the HTC Desire to Claro's internet?

Comment: @aescobal I have internet, but only EDGE as the model of HTC Desire I have, does not seem to support the band used by Claro, see the approved answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to a given 3G/3.5G network, your phone must support the correct [band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS_frequency_bands).

Based on the sparse information I was able to gather, it seems that [Claro](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claro_%28Per%C3%BA%29) is using bands II and V (1900 and 850)

It seems that there are at least [three](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdacomparer&id1=2120&id2=2365&id3=2251) different models of the HTC Desire, of which the **HTC Triumph / Desire US A8182** and **HTC Desire Telstra A8183** support bands II and V.  The third model, **HTC Desire A8181** supports bands I and VIII instead.

If your phone has the correct APN, supports the correct bands, and 3G is not disabled it should just work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, although it seems a bit more complicated than I was hoping for. I have an A8181 so I guess it's not going to work in Peru, I didn't realize 3G and normal GMS communication use different bands :-(

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to configure the APN.

Go to the Settings of your phone -> Wireless & Networks -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names.

Maybe you have none APN configured, so go to the menu to add one.

The list of APNs by country is here :

http://www.androidonhtc.com/wiki/Carrier_network_settings

In particular for Peru you have :

Claro Peru (America Movil)

- APN: wap.claro.pe

  Username: claro

  Password: claro

  Proxy: 192.168.231.30

  Port: 80

I hope that this information is useful. Regards!

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see, I already have the APN configured, I was wondering about 3G access instead of EDGE (which isn´t possible with my HTC Desire).